# How to use the with method in laravel to pass token to the view

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working on a reset system for mails registered in my application.
when the user receives the mail and clicks on the link, he will be guided to my page where I receive token and email and his new password and reset for him his password.

```
return view($view,  ['strings'=>$strings, 'email'=>$passwordReset->email])->with('token', $token);
```

as you can see here is the view i load to show to the user the password input.
the problem is i do not know how to send this token to the view. suppose i want it to be in an hidden input in my view.

the method which passes the token and email to the form looks like this

```
 public function getReset($token = null)
{
    $view = 'auth.web.reset2';

    if ( is_null( $token ) ) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }

    $passwordReset = PasswordReset::getEmailFromToken( $token );

    if ( is_null( $passwordReset ) ) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }

    $user = User::getUserFromEmail( $passwordReset->email );
    if ( is_null( $user ) ) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }

    if(User::isUserMobileClient($user)){
        //$view = 'auth.reset';
    }

    $strings = array(
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_01),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_02),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_03),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_04),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_05),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_06),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_051),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_07),
        trans(Strings::PASSWORD_RESET_BLADE_08),
    );

    return view($view,['strings'=>$strings, 'email'=>$passwordReset->email, 'token' => $token]);
}
```

and the method which is called when the user press the submit button is like this:

```
 public function postReset(Request $request)
{
    $userFromMobile = false;

    $this->validate($request, [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
        $this->user;
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    });

    if(User::isUserMobileClient(User::getUserFromgEmail($request->email))){
        $userFromMobile = true;
    }

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:

            Input::flashonly('status');

            return ($userFromMobile) ?
                redirect('password/changed')->with('status', trans($response)) :
                redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));

        default:
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that laravel as a build in Auth with reset password already in ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: But I'm not sure to understand your question. As I see you already are passing the token to the view ?

Comment: Yes this is not my code it is an already existing project and i dont want to mess with the legacy codes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this?

```
return view($view,['strings'=>$strings, 'email'=>$passwordReset->email, 'token' => $token]);
```

Comment: The token field is required.
The email field is required.

Comment: I send the token and email and still it shows me they are required. I do not understand why.

Comment: What does your controller look like??

Comment: Is your token is in a form ? `<input type="hidden" value="{{$token}}">` ?

Comment: I edited the question and added the methods which i use in controller.

Comment: Are you passing the token in the route? e.g. `password/reset/{token}` If not then how does the `getReset($token)` function ever get the token value?